# Using fit_generator in Keras Model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, sparse-matrix, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to train a neural network using Keras and Tensorflow backend. My `X` is text descriptions which I have processed and transformed into sequences. Now, my `y` is a sparse matrix since it's a multi-label classification and I have many output classes.

```
>>> y
<30405x3387 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 54971 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

To train the model, I tried defining a batch generator:

```
def batch_generator(x, y, batch_size=32):
    n_batches_per_epoch = x.shape[0]//batch_size
    for i in range(n_batches_per_epoch):
        index_batch = range(x.shape[0])[batch_size*i:batch_size*(i+1)]       
        x_batch = x[index_batch,:]
        y_batch = y[index_batch,:].todense()
        yield x_batch, np.array(y_batch)
```

I've divided my data as:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

I define my model as:

```
model = Sequential()
# Create architecture, add some layers.
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And I'm training my model as:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=batch_generator(x_train, y_train), steps_per_epoch=(x_train[0]/32), epochs=200, callbacks=the_callbacks)
```

But my model starts with around 55% accuracy and it quickly (in 2 or 3 steps) becomes 99.95%, which makes no sense at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it makes no sense at all? You have no validation data so there is no information if its overfitting or not.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It's overfitting in 2 steps? It sees 64 examples and it's overfitted already?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of overfitting, as I said before, you didn't provide information about validation metrics.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice, but I have 10 perfect of my training data for validation, and I'm generating it with the same `batch_generator` but on a different set. Anyways, the problem is the accuracy that Keras uses when you select `binary_crossentropy`, which is `binary_accuracy`, it should be `categorical_accuracy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to switch your loss to "categorical_crossentropy" or change your metric to "crossentropy" for multiclass classification.

The "accuracy" metric is actually ambiguous behind the scenes in Keras- it picks binary or multiclass accuracy based on the loss function used.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L375

Comment: Since I want all classes to be treated as independent classes I use binary_crossentropy. See [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) for further explanation on this

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes you can use sigmoid activation in the last layer and binary cross entropy loss function. But, if you have more than one classes, then you have to replace sigmoid with softmax and binary with categorical cross entropy.

There could be multiple other reasons for the abrupt change in accuracy depending upon your data distribution, model configuration etc. etc.

Comment: No exactly, I'm trying to predict multiple output classes and I want them to all be treated as independent. Refer [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/).

Comment: Got your point. You can solve this in multiple ways: (1) Use MSE loss function where batch_generator should return the probability of each class in 'y_batch' as [0, 1, 0, 1]. In this case, each output will be pushed either towards zero or one which would mimic the probability of that class. (2) You can use custom loss function where you have to compute binary cross entropy for each class independently and then add all losses as the total function for the gradient.